# Cascade validation on entities with Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm wondering how I can perform a cascade validation on an entity with the validator service.

Using:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errorList = $validator->validate($entity);
```

does not perform a validation of the "entity" children entities.

I'm pretty sure it can be done since its possible using the form validation (using `'cascade_validation' => true`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that (by default) validation is not processed on attributes that points to objects. It can be done for arrays with [the traverse option](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator.php#L96) of the `validate()` method set to `true`.

To bypass this limitation, you should consider using a [Valid Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html).

Check [this well explained example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html#basic-usage) of using the [Valid Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) and where processing validation on the parent object also checks the child's object validation rules.

The [Valid Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) also provides [a traverse option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html#traverse) that you can use to check attributes that point to an array of objects.

Comment: Just a quick note here. You cannot pass a validation group(s) to the Valid constraint - it only has the default one. You rarely need that, but keep in mind anyway. That's the limitation that I encoutered while using Valid constraint.