# How to validate merged forms in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony-2.7

I use a normal form in symfony2, which integrates with the following statement a second form.

```
    class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('task')
            ->add('dueDate', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            **->add('xyz', new xyzType())**
        ;
    }
}
```

everything is working fine but, the validation does only work for the main form (TaskType) the integrated form (xyzType() will **not checked** when i call:

```
$editForm->handleRequest($request);

     if ($editForm->isValid()) {
       //do something...
        }
```

Why the second Form does not receive this event?  What i do wrong?

Thanks for your Feedback!

Comment: I want to be sure I'm understanding you: `xyxType` should be causing `TaskType` to be marked as invalid when left unchecked - and it is not?

Comment: Consider, btw, if this Q and A don't both apply to you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548354/cascade-validation-on-entities-with-symfony2

Comment: You understood me totaly right! I Think that would be the solution and its really easy to do it! Sorry i really did not found a smart answer before..! Thanks you so much:)